# Use SNMPJS in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wanted to use SNMP to connect to printer and I came across this library - https://github.com/pdlove/react-native-snmp-native. However when I try to use the same in reactnative platform I get the error.

```
import snmp from 'net-snmp';
const session = snmp.createSession('10.20.27.221', 'public', 161);
const oids = ['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0'];

session.get(oids, (error, varbinds) => {
if (error) {
    console.error(error);
} else {
        console.log(varbinds[0].value);
  }
});
session.trap(snmp.TrapType.LinkDown, (error) => {
if (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
});
```

When I try to execute the above code i get the following error on android simulator

```
The development server returned response error code: 500
URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:
{"from":"/Users/Documents/projects/auth/node_modules/net-snmp/index.js","to":"dgram","message":"Unable to resolve module dgram from /Users/Documents/projects/auth/node_modules/net-snmp/index.js: Module does not exist in the module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all.\n 2. Delete the node_modules folder: rm -rf node_modules && npm install.\n 3. Reset packager cache: rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-* or npm start -- --reset-cache.","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]}
processBundleResult
BundleDownloader.java:225
access$100
BundleDownloader.java:40
onResponse
BundleDownloader.java:192
execute
RealCall.java:135
run
NamedRunnable.java:32
runWorker
ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162
run
ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636
run
Thread.java:764
```

**Has anyone used SNMP protocol using react native? What is the best way to go about it?**

Comment: did you run `react-native link` after you installed the package?

Comment: Yes I had did the same.